# Rails: displaying an image from a blob field in a database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, image

So, I managed to get an image blob into my MySQL database (there's a big hex number in the field), but I can't find any documentation on how to display the image in a rails environment... when it prints out, it starts with a GIF89... and then the gobbledygook characters you see in a GIF when you open it in Notepad.  : P  Any clues would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The following code should work. In your controller, create a method:

```
def show_image
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    send_data @user.image, :type => 'image/png',:disposition => 'inline'
end
```

In your view:

```
<%= image_tag url_for(:controller => "mycontroller", :action => "show_image", :id => @user.id) %>
```

I would recommend using the Paperclip gem. It makes saving/viewing of images really easy.

Comment: Thanks, that works.  Paperclip will probably be the way I ultimately go, but I needed a quick and dirty solution for demo purposes.

Comment: @wulftone. Glad to be of assistance.

Answer (score 16):

Because you mentioned "quick and dirty", I'll throw out this as an alternative-

```
<%= ('<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,%s">' % Base64.encode64(@the_data)).html_safe %>
```

I think this is closest to what you wanted to do.  There's a few reasons that this code shouldn't be used as-is, but it's simple.  I'd have to think more about how bad of an idea is it is to mark the whole thing as html_safe.  Also, this wouldn't work in older versions of IE.

Comment: I've just extracted it into a helper :)

Comment: I also wonder what `%s">' % Base64.encode64(@....`  part means??? (percent followed by s followed again by percent)

Answer (score 5):

You should also add

```
resources :users do
     get 'show_image', :on => :collection
 end
```

or

```
get users/show_image" => "users#show_image"
```

before

`resources :users` in **route.rb** file

Comment: @silvio Rails 4 will complaint: ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:controller=>"user_controller", :action=>"show_image", :id=>9777}):

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely a must for Rails 4