# Image not showing up from database in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Rails 4.1 and I created a User class.  When the user is created the can import an avatar.  However at best I have gotten an "image" to show up but it doesn't load the actual image from the database.

I then tried to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294427/rails-displaying-an-image-from-a-blob-field-in-a-database) post to fix it but now I am just getting "No Route Matches".  Here is my exact error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show_image", :controller=>"users_controller", :id=>"1"}
```

It claims it is coming from this line in my index.html.erb:

```
<%= image_tag url_for(:controller => "users_controller", :action => "show_image", :id => user.id) %>
```

Here is my controller:

```
 def show_image
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    send_data @user.avatar, :type => 'image/png', :disposition => 'inline'
 end
```

And my users index.html.erb:

```
<html>

  <head>
  </head>

   <body>
    <h1>Users</h1>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="1"></th>
      </tr>

      <% @users.each do |user| %>
        <tr>
          <%= image_tag url_for(:controller => "users_controller", :action => "show_image", :id => user.id) %>
          <td><%= user.username %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be highly appreciated.  Thanks ahead of time.

Edit:  This is what my routes look like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'sessions/login'
  get 'sessions/login_attempt'
  get 'sessions/home'
  get 'sessions/profile'
  get 'sessions/setting'
  get 'welcome/index'
  get 'users/new'

  post 'sessions/login_attempt'
  post 'sessions/logout'

  resources :users

  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

Edit:  I have also tried adding the following to the Routes file as suggested by @Question and @j0k in the thread I was following before:

```
resources :users do
  get 'show_image', :on => :collection
end
```

and

```
get 'users/show_image' => 'users#show_image'
```

I also tried this

```
get 'users/show_image'
```

However I still got the same error.

Missing Image Icon that I get:
[image]

Two lines from my Users class where I add in avatar:

```
has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

When looking up the images in the database this is what I found... I ran the following command:

```
sqlite> select avatar_file_name, avatar_content_type, avatar_file_size from users;
```

and got:

```
|image/png|660726
|image/gif|3614
|image/png|282
```

...so it is getting no file name.

When I looked up the file in the path I found that in this:
/public/system/users/avatars/000/000/001/original my image 'up.png' existed.  It also existed in ../medium and ../thumb as well.

Edit:  Update from @RichPeck advice.

So I was <%= image_tag @user.avatar.url %> ...instead this is what I was doing...

```
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <tr>
      <%= image_tag user.avatar.url %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

I am somewhat confused on how <%= image_tag @user.avatar.url %> would get a specific user's Avatar.  Doesn't @user reference All Users?  However, I tried @RichPeck suggestion anyway.  I added both <%= image_tag @user.avatar.url %> and <%= debug @user.avatar %>.  But both gave me the following error:

```
undefined method `avatar' for nil:NilClass
```

Edit:  I just went through the Paperclip tutorial and compared it to what I have.  I found a few differences but I don't think any of it would make a big difference.  However, I will post it here so if anyone knows what is going wrong they can help.

**Edit or New Views**

Paperclip

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => users_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |form| %>
 <%= form.file_field :avatar %>
<% end %>
```

My code (The main thing I would be concerned about is the :url => but I think it should be fine)

```
<%= form_for(:user, :url => {:controller => 'users', :action => 'create'}, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
  <p> Username:</br> <%= f.text_field :username%> </p>
  <p> Email:</br> <%= f.text_field :email%> </p>
  <p> Password:</br> <%= f.password_field :password%></p>
  <p> Password Confirmation:</br> <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation%> </p>
  <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
  <%= f.submit :Signup %>
<% end %>
```

**Controller**

Paperclip

```
def create
  @user = User.create( user_params )
end

private

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:avatar)
end
```

My Code

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    flash[:notice] = "You signed up successfully"
    flash[:color]= "valid"
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Form is invalid"
    flash[:color]= "invalid"
  end
  render "new"
end

private

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password, :avatar)
end
```

Edit:  After looking at it for a bit I realized I was trying to access the users page w/o my session.  I was doing localhost:3000/users not localhost:3000/users?id=1. So my ID was never being passed.

I had to add the following to my Users Controller:

```
def index
  @users = User.all
  @user = User.find(params[:id])  # <--- Added this line
end
```

However, <%= image_tag @user.avatar.url %> still shows the default blank image.  But I have been able to get <%= debug @user.avatar %> to work.  This is the output for the debug command.

```
--- &70308396554900 !ruby/object:Paperclip::Attachment
name: :avatar
instance: !ruby/object:User
  attributes:
    id: 1
    username: jones1
    email: stupid1@stupid.com
    encrypted_password: $2a$10$dvvLzRCQQVngFpt5TfPqJOtU8s02GUj6UOHlzibWi1CaQFY1BA8tS
    salt: $2a$10$dvvLzRCQQVngFpt5TfPqJO
    created_at: 2014-05-10 05:19:07.138281000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-05-10 05:19:07.138281000 Z
    avatar_file_name: 
    avatar_content_type: image/png
    avatar_file_size: 397
    avatar_updated_at: 2014-05-10 05:19:06.715067000 Z
options: &70308396554880
  :convert_options: {}
  :default_style: :original
  :default_url: /images/:style/missing.png
  :escape_url: true
  :restricted_characters: !ruby/regexp /[&$+,\/:;=?@<>\[\]\{\}\|\\\^~%# ]/
  :filename_cleaner: 
  :hash_data: ':class/:attachment/:id/:style/:updated_at'
  :hash_digest: SHA1
  :interpolator: &70308352640280 !ruby/module 'Paperclip::Interpolations'
  :only_process: []
  :path: ':rails_root/public:url'
  :preserve_files: false
  :processors:
  - :thumbnail
  :source_file_options: &70308351975980 {}
  :storage: :filesystem
  :styles:
    :medium: 300x300>
    :thumb: 100x100>
  :url: /system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename
  :url_generator: !ruby/class 'Paperclip::UrlGenerator'
  :use_default_time_zone: true
  :use_timestamp: true
  :whiny: true
  :check_validity_before_processing: true
post_processing: true
queued_for_delete: []
queued_for_write: {}
errors: {}
dirty: false
interpolator: *70308352640280
url_generator: !ruby/object:Paperclip::UrlGenerator
  attachment: *70308396554900
  attachment_options: *70308396554880
source_file_options: *70308351975980
whiny: true
```

Edit:  Last edit for the night before I have to go to sleep.  I also did <%= debug @user.avatar.url %> and it returned the following:  --- /images/original/missing.png?1399954308

Comment: You didn't specify the root for "show_image" action in your routes.rb file

Comment: @anusha I edited my answer.  I tried adding it to my routes file but still get the same error.  Am I doing something wrong when I am trying to add it to my Routes file?

Comment: Why are you passing the username as id. So I am guessing that is the reason why it can't find the user. Try: <%= image_tag url_for(:controller => "users_controller", :action => "show_image", :id => user.id) %>

Comment: Try to change the route get 'users/show_image' => 'users#show_image' to match "show_image" => "users#show_image" and also change this line to <%= image_tag url_for(:controller => "users", :action => "show_image", :id => user.id) %>

Comment: @anusha Good catch on the id.  I changed it in both my view and my controller.  However I still am receiving the error.  When I tried using the Match that you mentioned I got an error saying that I should not try to use Match.

Comment: @GeorgeAstonishing Good catch on the id.  I changed it on both my controller and view.  However I am still getting the error :/

Comment: are you still getting routing error?

Comment: FYI: `match` does not work with Rails 4. i'm talking about matching routes in `routes.rb` file. if that's what you were referring to

Comment: Also in your current setup have you tried to write :controller => "users" instead of :controller => "users_controller" ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `paperclip`, and to help maintain clarity for anyone looking at this in future:

**Paperclip**

> When you use Paperclip, it creates an object & appends to your
>   original ActiveRecord object. When you define `has_attached_file :____`, the name of that element is what the Paperclip object is
>   called, meaning you'll be able to call @user.____ to access it

The problem you have is you're using another process to load your image. This is totally unnecessary as, as pointed out in the comments, `Paperclip` automatically assigns the [`.url` method](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#show-view) to the appended Paperclip object

You *should* be able to call `<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url %>` to output the relvant image. I know you know this, but I want to help anyone who may look at this thread in future

---

**Error**

In terms of your error, having looked at your comments & updates, it seems like it's either a problem with how you're calling the image, or perhaps how it's stored in the db

Can you do this for us:

```
<%= debug @user.avatar #-> this will show the entire avatar object %>
```

I believe your db will not have the correct columns, hence Paperclip pulling the wrong filename or something. There will be a really trivial error somewhere

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late response.  Work got crazy so it was a while before I was able to get back to this project.  So when I called both <%= debug @user.avatar %> and <%= image_tag @user.avatar.url %> I get the following error:  undefined method `avatar' for nil:NilClass.  Also, updating OP to explain more.

Answer (score -1):

In general the setup appears to be fairly complicated - considering you want to display a user image. For simply things like user image I am using paperclip for my projects: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip .. you may want to take a look at it. It automates image upload, resize, etc. I used it in several projects and never hit any issues.

If that's not what you need, perhaps you let me know what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: I actually am using paperclip.  However when I originally tried showing my image using "<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url %>" it didn't work.  It displays an empty image (not the one stored in the db).

Comment: Ok, with empty image you mean that it doesn't show an image at all (you get the image missing icon?). If so, did you make sure that it gets stored in the db? Make sure avatar_file_name is not null. In case it is null - make sure you add :avatar to your permitted parameters.

Comment: I edited my post to show the image I get.  I did a <%= users.avatar %> to see what the value was and it is this:  /avatars/original/missing.png?1399177310  ...I imagine some of that has to do with my default URL that is setup via paperclip?

Comment: Also put the two lines where I add avatar in my OP

Comment: Can you take a look at the user table and check the value of avatar_file_name. The fact that missing.png is showing up when you query for user.avatar make me believe that there is no image.

Comment: Also check if the image is in <root_folder>/public/system/users/avatars/000/... (the path might be slightly different in your case).

Comment: OP updated to answer your questions.  Oddly enough it seems my file name isn't being saved but everything else for my avatar is.

Comment: Upload another image and check the server output. Tried to reproduce the issue ... no luck

Comment: Sorry work got a little bit crazy so I had to leave this (my side project) for later.  I tried uploading a few other images but no luck.  Same results.