# how to properly display image from database in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Am new to ruby on rails. Here Am trying to display image from database. To this effect, I leverage solution found here
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294427/rails-displaying-an-image-from-a-blob-field-in-a-database). but when I run my script it displays error

`No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"attachments_controller", :id=>17}`
Please what am I doing wrong with the route.
**Routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


   resources :attachments, only: [:index, :new, :create, :destroy]
   root "attachments#create"

   get "attachments/show" => "attachments#show"

end
```

**attachments_controller**

```
class AttachmentsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @attachment = Attachment.find(params[:id])
    send_data @attachment.data, :filename => @attachment.filename, :type => @attachment.content_type
  end
end
```

**show.html**

```
<%= image_tag url_for(:controller => "attachments_controller", :action => "show", :id => @attachment.id) %>
```

Comment: Haven't seen this syntax for a while. What version of Ruby and Ruby on Rails are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message you provided states:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"attachments_controller", :id=>17}
```

The routes file you provided shows the routes you created:

```
resources :attachments, only: [:index, :new, :create, :destroy]
get "attachments/show" => "attachments#show"
```

Running rake routes will show that you've created the 4 routes in the first line, plus a route that responds to 'attachments/show'. If you really want to define the route like this, you should try:

```
get "attachments/:id", to: "attachments/show"
```

Your first route only responds to the word show, and would supply no params. The last route will take whatever comes after attachments, and pass it to the show action of the attachments controller as a paramater called 'id'.

Of course the easiest way to do all of that is to get rid of it all, and simply change the first route to:

```
resources :attachments, only: [:index, :new, :create, :destroy, :show]
```

Letting rails create the show route for you is exactly the same as manually defining it, and obviously reads a lot better

Comment: Hello Sir Mark, I have tried your both solution but the same error above keeps coming

Comment: Thanks Its working now. I used attachments_controller instead of just attachments

Comment: Happy it's working :) But you can get rid of that line completely by just using the last line, `resources :attachments, only: [:index, :new, :create, :destroy, :show]`. That will automatically make the route that you are looking for :)

Comment: am using the last line like you said. thanks. its high time i upvote your answer.

Comment: Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<%= image_tag url_for(:controller => "attachments_controller", :action => "show", :id => @attachment.id) %>
```

to

```
<%= image_tag url_for(:controller => "attachments", :action => "show", :id => @attachment.id) %>
```